# How can I get color from the image via URL in expo

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, expo

I am working on an expo project and need to get the average color of the image using the URL of that image I found a package but it is not supported on expo.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-colors

How can use this package in an expo or let me know is there any package for expo to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar project but I cannot found any similar packages for expo.

If you really want to get the color from the image, I believe the only way is to eject from expo or create the application using react-native-cli package.